# oAuth: How to integrate Twitter and LinkedIn in the same app?

Tags: iphone, twitter, oauth, linkedin-api

I have integrated Twitter and Facebook in my iPhone App successfully.
Also Facebook and LinkedIn API is implemented successfully in many of my apps.

But when I try to integrate Twitter and LinkedIn in the same app it gives me error as below and crashes the app:

```
-[OAConsumer initWithKey:secret:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x61677b0
2011-09-15 18:58:41.675 thelifedoctor[8086:207] *** Terminating app due to  uncaughtexception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[OAConsumer   initWithKey:secret:]:unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x61677b0'
```

So basically **Twitter + Facebook Works Fine**. Also **Facebook + LinkedIn works fine**. But **Twitter + LinkedIn gives errors**.

I have gone through almost every answered and unanswered question related to this problem on Stack Overflow but none has been helpful until now.

I Googled about it and found that it has something to do with the issue that both LinkedIn and Twiiter have the oAuthentication so some files are confusing the compiler.

What should I do so that I can integrate both the APIs successfully in my app?

Is there a way where in we can implement both Twitter and LinkedIn in the same app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Used Twitpic Library for iOS and it worked great for me.

Thanks Everyone :)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem as you and I just duplicate the files that confused and renamed it. I know that it's not the best solution, but at least it works.